# Google Cloud equivalent of Azure's Data Science VM

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, azure-dsvm

I need a packaged Virtual Machine on Google Cloud with the following installed already:

1. Python (2.x, 3.x, Anaconda distro)
2. R
3. A database server (PostGreSQL etc)
4. Ipython/Jupyter/JupyterHub
5. Deep Learning Libraries (Tensorflow, Keras and GPU support CUDANN)

These are usually available in Amazon's AMI or MS Azure's Data Science Instances.

Links:
1. [Amazon's AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01M0AXXQB#product-description)!
2. [Microsoft's VM](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.linux-data-science-vm-ubuntu)!

Could someone experienced please guide me in finding the right VM, if such a VM is indeed available on Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Just build your image with all the packages you need.

Comment: Building it up from scratch especially the deep learning libraries with CUDANN seems like a daunting task for a **novice** (like me) as if swimming in a sea of version/driver conflicts and what not. I'd rather stick to pre configured instances from Google if possible. If MS and AWS provide it, I presumed there would be something available on GCP  already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Closest that comes to your requirement google datalab though it does not satisfy all,
https://cloud.google.com/datalab/

If you want more control over your VM this article will help you a great deal

https://haroldsoh.com/2016/04/28/set-up-anaconda-ipython-tensorflow-julia-on-a-google-compute-engine-vm/

If not as a workaround you can, install docker on your VM,

For R and PostGreSQL pull the prebuilt dockers and follow the simple instructions in dockerhub

https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base/

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Go to the following repo and get the most suitable docker for your VM, instructions are added on git as well,

https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker

This includes the following,

CUDA 8.0 (GPU version only)
cuDNN v5 (GPU version only)
Tensorflow
Caffe
Theano
Keras
Lasagne
Torch (includes nn, cutorch, cunn and cuDNN bindings)
iPython/Jupyter Notebook (including iTorch kernel)
Numpy, SciPy, Pandas, Scikit Learn, Matplotlib
OpenCV
and A few common libraries used for deep learning

This should be enough to satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the docker route to my question. I have never tried dockers myself, I understand the method involved. I will give this a go.

Comment: Please humor me on this, would it be possible to create a docker from AWS's / Azure's Data Science VMs and use the same on Google's VM?

Comment: The simpler solution would be to migrate your existing VM https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/migrating-vms-compute-engine and if this anwer provider you with a solution can you mark it as the correct one :D

Comment: Thanks!! Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

GCP now has own DeepLearning images for GCE. You can find information about them [here](https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/deep-learning-images-for-google-cloud-engine-the-definitive-guide-bc74f5fb02bc).